# Using hideBarsOnSwipe with UIViewController containing UITableView

Tags: uitableview, ios8, uinavigationbar, show-hide, swipe-gesture

I have a problem while using hideBarsOnSwipe;

If I use it on a UIViewController, everything goes fine. But when using UITableViewController, I think its swipe gesture recogniser conflicts with the UITableView's. So table swiping great, but sometimes -generally if you swipe too slow- it's not hiding or showing. But the main problem is this: If I use hideBarsOnSwipe on a UIViewController which contains a UITableView, it is not working on the UITableView. -but working on the other UI elements, which are not have a swipe gesture-.

So, can anyone guide me about this? Am I missing something, or is it normal, or is it a bug?

**Edit**: I'm working with Objective-C, X-Code 6.1 and iOS8. Didn't try on iOS7.

Comment: I have the same problem. If I use a UIViewController containing a UITableView, the status bar won't hide on dragging the UITableView. But swiping other UIView-Elements within the UIView, it works.